# Excel: Add month to previous date incrementally, giving same date for all months

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to sequential dates over a period of months based on the given input date.

[image]

Current excel formula: `=--(MONTH(B2+32) & "/" & DAY(B$2) & "/" & YEAR(B2+32))`

Input date format: `DD-MM-YYYY`

Version: Microsoft office Home and Student 2019

Can someone please provide the excel formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `EDATE` function, to add or subtract a specified number of months to a date and return the new date.

It works like this:

```
=EDATE(startdate,months)
```

Example (to add 1 month to the input date):

```
=EDATE(B2,1)
```